# Execution of do while loop in the Java Calculator program

Tags: java, calculator, do-while

In my Java Program, I have used a Boolean variable 'decision' which should execute the actual calculator code in the 'do loop code block' only when the variable is true, but the do while loop is executed anyways even when the decision variable is false. I am using Eclipse IDE for Java and JDK 10 (both are recent versions). Please help me with a solution. The code is as below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class apples {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int option,a,b,c;
    boolean decision;
    System.out.println("We are here to create a calculator");
    System.out.print("Do you want to switch on the calculator:");
    Scanner yogi = new Scanner(System.in);
    decision = yogi.nextBoolean();
    do {
        System.out.println("Following operations are available to perform:");
        System.out.println("1. Addition");
        System.out.println("2. Subtraction");
        System.out.println("3. Multiplication");
        System.out.println("4. Division");
        System.out.print("Enter the operations do you want to perform:");
        option = yogi.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Choice of operation is:"+option);

        switch(option) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Enter two numbers to be added:");
            a = yogi.nextInt();
            b = yogi.nextInt();
            c = a + b;
            System.out.print("Addition:"+c);
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Enter two numbers to be subtracted:");
            a = yogi.nextInt();
            b = yogi.nextInt();
            c = a - b;
            System.out.print("subtracted:"+c);
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("Enter two numbers to be multiplied:");
            a = yogi.nextInt();
            b = yogi.nextInt();
            c = a * b;
            System.out.print("multiplied:"+c);
            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println("Enter two numbers to be divided:");
            a = yogi.nextInt();
            b = yogi.nextInt();
            c = a / b;
            System.out.print("divided:"+c);
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("This is a wrong choice");
            break;
        }
    }while(decision==true);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could use an if/else to determine if you want do loop. Or you simply change to use a pure while loop instead.

Comment: That is what a `do..while` loop is for. The body will be executed at least once. Use a while loop

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions and fixes. Helped me. Issue is solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the do while loop is executed anyways even when the decision variable
>   is false

A `do...while` will executes the body once before checking the condition.

Either modify your code for `while` or add an `if-else` enclosing `do...while`.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions and fixes. Helped me. Issue is solved!

Answer (score 1):

You can add another `case 5` and in that write `System.exit(0)` for the successful termination of the program.

In the `while` part pass `(option != 5)`. This should run the program.
You don't need decision variable.